# Issue encountered executing Selenium Java code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, java-package

To get started, you need to import following two packages:

- `org.openqa.selenium.*`- contains the WebDriver class needed to instantiate a new browser loaded with a specific driver
- `org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver` - contains the FirefoxDriver class needed to instantiate a Firefox-specific driver onto the browser instantiated by the WebDriver class

If your test needs more complicated actions such as accessing another class, taking browser screenshots, or manipulating external files, definitely you will need to import more packages.
Not able to understand the code?

```
package newproject;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//comment the above line and uncomment below line to use Chrome
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class PG1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //comment the above 2 lines and uncomment below 2 lines to use Chrome
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\chromedriver.exe");
        //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/newtours/";
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
        String actualTitle = "";

        // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        // get the actual value of the title
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

        /*
         * compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and print
         * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
         */
        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }
       
        //close Fire fox
        driver.close();
       
    }

}
```

Comment: What it the problem?

Comment: Are you struggling to understand code from another source? If so, I would recommend asking the author, not SO

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: What's the problem? what's the error?

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine. You only need to change:

This line of your code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
```

To this line:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
```